# How can i find all windows with a particular _NET_WM_NAME?

Tags: x11

I need to set a custom property for all windows which have a particular window name.

I tried to first list all windows with the particular name and the problem i faced was that xprop or xwininfo would only list me details for one instance of that window inspite of multiple windows with the same name being available.

```
xprop -name 'xyz'
xwininfo -name 'xyz'
```

Eventually i will be using the below command to set the custom property

```
xprop -name 'xyz' -f Onkar 8s -set Onkar Hello
```

Another thing to note is that i dont have access to wmctrl or xdotool

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a programmatic approach (in C) :

First, get the window IDs using _NET_CLIENT_LIST property using Atoms and XGetWindowProperty().
Then get the window names using WM_NAME under Atoms, again using XGetWindowProperty(). Now you have the list of all active windows in your system, so you can use strcmp() to check the desired name of the window.

The working code is given here:
https://cboard.cprogramming.com/linux-programming/125534-accessing-windows-x11.html

About XGetWindowProperty() 
https://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/window-information/XGetWindowProperty.html

About Atoms:
https://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/window-information/properties-and-atoms.html